# Accessibility Focus not being updated on custom control slider when thumb moves

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2, voiceover

I have a custom slider based of UIControl and the accessibility works as expected except for the focus on voiceover doesn't reflects/updates when the thumb moves to left or right. I have set the trait as adjustable and also overridden accessibilityIncrement and accessibilityDecrement but the focus doesn't updates automatically.

Comment: would you mind posting the code you wrote specifying the place you have overridden the 'increment' and 'decrement' methods to be as accurate as possible in the answer, please?

Comment: @topgun did you find any fix for this problem?